# Unexpected gcm unregistered message when gcm.unregister() has never been called

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

This only happens on my Kyocera Rise. I have an app that depends on GCM to communicate between phones. The communication between my Nexus 4 and my HTC One X works fine, with both phones receiving intents with the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE action whenever I send push notifications. However, running the exact same code on the Kyocera Rise yields a completely different result: whenever I send it a push notification, the received intent has the action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION with the "unregistered" extra parameter. Even if I send it a push notification within seconds of it successfully registering with Google (it has to be successful for me to retrieve the device ID to use for push) the result is an unregistered message. Why?

EDIT: here's a clearer picture of what's going on.
All my other phones: I register phone -> I send push notification -> phone receives com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE intent with the message extras

Kyrocera Rise: I register phone -> I wait for any amount of time (doesn't matter if it's 0 seconds or 5 minutes, there won't be a single push notification received) -> I send push notification -> phone immediately receives com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent with the "unregistered" extra parameter

EDIT 2: Relevant parts of the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="edu.neu.madcourse.wanfunglee.comm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="edu.neu.madcourse.wanfunglee.comm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="4242000" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="edu.neu.madcourse.wanfunglee.comm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: What Android version is on the Kyrocera device? Can you post you android manifest?

Comment: It's 4.0.4. Edited with manifest.

Comment: Do you define the `edu.neu.madcourse.wanfunglee.comm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE` permission anywhere in your manifest? And is `edu.neu.madcourse.wanfunglee.comm` the main package of your app?

Comment: Much thanks, the package name was the issue. I thought it was supposed to be the package of the broadcast receiver itself. If you'll add it as the answer I'll be happy to accept it. Strange how it works before these changes in phones running 4.2.2 and 4.4.2 however.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I noticed that only older Android versions require these definitions in the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the main package of your app is used in the manifest in the C2D_MESSAGE permission and in the category of the GCM broadcast receiver.